# How can I debounce using async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, lodash, debouncing

I have an input box. After the user has stopped typing, I want to perform an HTTP request and await the results.

[Here's a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/towudev/edit?html,js,output)

Since network requests aren't allowed on jsbin, I've used `setTimeout()` instead.

```
var log = console.log.bind(console)

var delayedResults = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve('Wooo I am the result!')
  }, 3000);
});

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', _.debounce(async function(){
  log('Doing search')
  var result = await delayedResults
  log('Result is', result)
}), 500);
```

However when I type in the box, 'Doing search' appears immediately every character - I want it to only appear after the 500ms has expired.

How can I use debounce and await?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write async function with Lodash in a Vuejs component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422806/write-async-function-with-lodash-in-a-vuejs-component)

Comment: @BenRacicot that’s a newer question. So that question is a duplicate of this, depending on whether the asker confirms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was at the last line:

```
}), 500);
```

You should close `debounce` function call **after** time argument was specified:

```
}, 500));
```

```js
var log = console.log.bind(console);

var delayedResults = new Promise(
  function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('Wooo I am the result!');
    }, 3000);
  }
);

document.querySelector('input')
  .addEventListener('keydown', _.debounce(async function() {
    log('Doing search');
    var result = await delayedResults;
    log('Result is', result);
  }, 500));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Comment: Ooh subtle! I think it passed linting so I didn't notice. Thank you!