# Vue async method with timeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component

I am using the [spatie datatables](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component#retrieving-data-asynchronously) component, retrieving data asynchronously and pagination.

What I would like, is for a delay to be allowed for between each keyup in the filter box before issuing an ajax call to get the data.

Traditionally in JavaScript I would do this by adding a keyup event on the input with a timeout, but I'm not sure how to do this with a Vue component.

My current component method looks like;

```
async fetchData({ page, filter, sort }) {

    const response =  await axios.get(this.getUrl(), this.getParams({
        page: page,
        filter: filter,
        sort: sort
    }));

    return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look on combination with `lodash.debounce` method. Similar question posted here: [How can I debounce using async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501653/how-can-i-debounce-using-async-await)